# PHP Form, Addresses with the # symbol causes url error and unidentified index

Tags: php, url, get

I know my title isn't very clear. 
But I am currently doing a CRUD webpage which allows the administrator to edit user details.
So the user details are displayed in a table with edit and delete links located at every row. 
So one of the user details consists of an address containing the # symbol
And when the admin clicks on edit, which is this link:

```
<td><a href='edit.php?operation=edit&user_id=".$user_id."&shipping_address=".$shipping_address."&billing_address=".$billing_address. "'>Edit</a></td>";
```

the URL will contain the # symbol and the data retrieved using $_GET is either cut away or unidentified index.

So my question is, is there anyway to use the # symbol in the URL without affecting my $_GET method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `urlencode($url)` before passing it to the link.